# GCM, how do I know end of XMPP packet?

Tags: python, sockets, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a Google Cloud Messaging XMPP server in Python. I can connect and authenticate to the GCM, however I use `self.ssl_sock.recv(1024)` which isn't good, but works for the auth.

However when I later on want to receive messages from the GCM I read on the socket, but how many bytes do I read?? I can't find anything in the xmpp docs about some kind of header which tell length of packet/data.

```
def read_from_socket(self):
        data = self.ssl_sock.recv(??)
        self.handle_message(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMPP does not use framing, so there is no header. You need to parse the XML stream using a streaming (e.g SAX) XML parser, such as expat. The XMPP equivalent of a "packet" can be determined by tracking the depth of the parser tree.

However if you're new to XMPP, I *strongly* recommend using  library instead of trying to write all this correctly from scratch yourself.

You're using Python. A good library to start with is SleekXMPP, which is also the library used for code examples in [XMPP: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521271.do) book.

More info:

- Github: https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP
- Docs: http://sleekxmpp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sleekxmpp

Comment: I ended up reading until I got a end tag, eg. '</message>' or similar. However your solution is the better way to do it. I'm doing this to learn Python, and the python server will never replace my current running one.

Comment: Just so you know, your solution is not correct because it's perfectly valid to have nested message tags. A simple practical example would be when forwarding a message: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0297.html#example-2

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that, however that kind of message will "never" be sent from google cloud messaging. But as you say I might implement so I can check that all tags/elements are closed before finishing reading.